# Format time in 24 hour format instead of AM/PM

Tags: microsoft-excel

When I format a cell in Excel to `HH:MM:SS` on selecting that cell it's show in `12:50:45 AM`.
I need it to display `00:50:45`.

Comment: You do know you can select time and just select the 24 hour format?

Comment: Do you mean that it displays as 12:50:45 AM in the cell itself or the formula bar? Assuming the former then if the format is HH:MM:SS and it displays in a different format that would indicate that you have a text value (which won't be changed by formatting) - if data is in cell A1 what do you get with this formula in B1 =ISNUMBER(A1)? FALSE indicates text

Answer (score 5):

You can just add a custom format of:

```
HH:MM:SS
```

Or use a formula like so:

```
=TEXT(A1,"HH:MM:SS")
```

Comment: And where exactly do you "just add a custom format"? Not a great answer.

Answer (score 2):

The time display format in Excel is set to 24 hours, but selecting the cell to edit the time insisted on 12 hour format during edit.
Fix: In windows7 control panel, region and Language, Formats, Additional Settings, Time..  set Long Time to HH:mm:ss ...  editing is now 24 hour format.
~ This is a windows setting, so obviously changes other program formats

Comment: You can certainly change the format of a cell in Excel without changing Windows settings.

Comment: This is the only one solution that worked for me, because I want the 24hs format in the formula bar in every excel sheet without applying any format. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

*If simply you want to replace the HOUR's value with ZERO for the TIME in Cell, then apply this as Cell Format.*

`"00:"mm:ss`

[image]

**Caveat**

- Purposely I've written a formula in Cell `R32` to justify, that Cell `Q32` still has TIME Value.

`=TIME(HOUR(Q32)+1,MINUTE(Q32),SECOND(Q32))`

- You may skip formula in Cell `R32`.

---

*If you only want to replace `12 Hrs` with ZERO then you may use this Formula.*

`=IF(HOUR(Q32)=12,"00:"&TEXT(Q32,"mm:ss"),Q32)`

**N.B.** Cell `Q36` has `GENERAL` format.

*You may adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.*